# Need to prove that $f=0$ given that f is an entire function and $|f(1/n)|<\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all n in natural numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

I've seen that, as f is an entire function, I can write its Taylor series expansion around z=0 and prove that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all n but, I 've got a lot of problems when trying to prove it by induction. I don't know if there is an easier way to prove this fact or maybe see the problem from a different point of view.

Comment: Do you know of Identity theorem?

Comment: No sir. Haven't heard about it

Comment: If you proved that $f(0) =0$, then $z=0$ is a root, so your function can be written as $f(z) = z\cdot g(z)$ You can take derivatives and conclude that $g(0)=0$ from where you can repeat the argument.